# how to change the url using php and ajax without reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

I want to make a web site that when login page redirected to a profile page the url changed to the user name as bellow( such as facebook) . 
If the URL is :

> localhost/profile.php

How to change it to :

> localhost/username

that's my code : (my problem is commented within )

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['changeUrl'])){
    $url= "/newUrl";
    echo $url;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        changeUrl(history.state);
        function changeUrl(){
                var currentState = history.state;
                $.ajax({
                    url :currentState ,
                    data : {changeUrl : "changeUrl"}  ,
                    type : 'post' ,
                    success : function(replacementState){
                        alert(replacementState);
                        //the return string from the alert function is "/newUrl<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...all between....</html>"

                        window.history.pushState(currentState, "", replacementState);
                    },
                });
        }
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't echo anything before the `<doctype>` and you can't set the `pushState` with all that html being returned either. Nothing in code shown shows source of `username`. Seems like you haven't thought this  through very thoroughly and need to study some tutorials

Comment: You could extract the `/newUrl` using string manipulation methods.

Comment: Try to window.location = "newurl.html"